# No "not equals" constraint in Gurobi

Tags: modeling, constraint, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi and trying to set a constraint that two variables `A`, `B` are not equal `model.addConstr(A != B)` and seems like there isn't a not equal sign in Gurobi library. Is there any mathematical intuition that why we can't perform not equal in Optimization?

Comment: I believe the mathematical intuition is that an inequality constraint like $A \neq B$ (as well as constraints like $A \lneqq B$) causes the feasible region to be not a closed set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want $x_1\neq x_2$, you can linearize $|x_1-x_2|\ge \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is your tolerance.

You can do this by introducing a boolean variable $y=1$ if and only if $x_1-x_2\ge \varepsilon$, and by imposing:

$$
x_1-x_2\le -\varepsilon +My\quad \mbox{and}\quad x_1-x_2\ge \varepsilon-(1-y)M
$$

$M$ is the smallest large constant you can think of.

Comment: For integer formulations, epsilon=1 and M=max of x1 - min of x2 + 1.